# Best way to create generic/method consistency for sort.data.frame?

Tags: class, generics, r, methods

I've finally decided to put the sort.data.frame method that's floating around the internet into an R package.  It just gets requested too much to be left to an ad hoc method of distribution.

However, it's written with arguments that make it incompatible with the generic sort function:

```
sort(x,decreasing,...)
sort.data.frame(form,dat)
```

If I change `sort.data.frame` to take decreasing as an argument as in `sort.data.frame(form,decreasing,dat)` and discard decreasing, then it loses its simplicity because you'll always have to specify `dat=` and can't really use positional arguments.  If I add it to the end as in `sort.data.frame(form,dat,decreasing)`, then the order doesn't match with the generic function.  If I hope that decreasing gets caught up in the dots `sort.data.frame(form,dat,...), then when using position-based matching I believe the generic function will assign the second position to decreasing and it will get discarded.  What's the best way to harmonize these two functions?

The full function is:

```
# Sort a data frame
sort.data.frame <- function(form,dat){
# Author: Kevin Wright
# http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/09/4300.html
# Some ideas from Andy Liaw
# http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/07/1076.html
# Use + for ascending, - for decending.
# Sorting is left to right in the formula
# Useage is either of the following:
# sort.data.frame(~Block-Variety,Oats)
# sort.data.frame(Oats,~-Variety+Block)

# If dat is the formula, then switch form and dat
  if(inherits(dat,"formula")){
    f=dat
    dat=form
    form=f
  }
  if(form[[1]] != "~") {
    stop("Formula must be one-sided.")
  }
# Make the formula into character and remove spaces
  formc <- as.character(form[2])
  formc <- gsub(" ","",formc)
# If the first character is not + or -, add +
  if(!is.element(substring(formc,1,1),c("+","-"))) {
    formc <- paste("+",formc,sep="")
  }
# Extract the variables from the formula
  vars <- unlist(strsplit(formc, "[\\+\\-]"))
  vars <- vars[vars!=""] # Remove spurious "" terms
# Build a list of arguments to pass to "order" function
  calllist <- list()
  pos=1 # Position of + or -
  for(i in 1:length(vars)){
    varsign <- substring(formc,pos,pos)
    pos <- pos+1+nchar(vars[i])
    if(is.factor(dat[,vars[i]])){
      if(varsign=="-")
        calllist[[i]] <- -rank(dat[,vars[i]])
      else
        calllist[[i]] <- rank(dat[,vars[i]])
    }
    else {
      if(varsign=="-")
        calllist[[i]] <- -dat[,vars[i]]
      else
        calllist[[i]] <- dat[,vars[i]]
    }
  }
  dat[do.call("order",calllist),]
}
```

Example:

```
library(datasets)
sort.data.frame(~len+dose,ToothGrowth)
```

Comment: The function `arrange` in the `plyr` package may be of some interest.

Comment: It is.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like it supports negative (backwards) sorts, so this function still appears to be useful.

Comment: I'm fairly sure `arrange` does support negative sorts: `arrange(ToothGrowth,desc(dose),len)`.

Comment: Wrote a full answer with plyr - thanks for the example @joran !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems there. `sort.data.frame` needs to have the same arguments as the generic, so at a minimum it needs to be

```
sort.data.frame(x, decreasing = FALSE, ...) {
....
}
```

To have dispatch work, the first argument needs to be the object dispatched on. So I would start with:

```
sort.data.frame(x, decreasing = FALSE, formula = ~ ., ...) {
....
}
```

where `x` is your `dat`, `formula` is your `form`, and we provide a default for formula to include everything. (I haven't studied your code in detail to see exactly what `form` represents.)

Of course, you don't need to specify `decreasing` in the call, so:

```
sort(ToothGrowth, formula = ~ len + dose)
```

would be how to call the function using the above specifications.

Otherwise, if you don't want `sort.data.frame` to be an S3 generic, call it something else and then you are free to have whatever arguments you want.

Comment: With partial matching, it isn't so bad to write `sort(ToothGrowth, f = ~ len + dose)` so that's why I did and kept the S3ness of it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Shouldn't we define a `sort.data.frame.formula` that would take a formula as first argument, and if it fails the formula test in `Use.method` would then dispatch to sort.data.frame that takes a first data argument? (Same as the situation with `aggregate.*`)

Comment: @DWin You mean `sort.formula`, yes?

Comment: I was thinking I wanted it to drop back to a `sort.data.frame.default` method or `sort.dataframe` that would accept a first argument as a dataframe.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `arrange` function in `plyr`.  It allows you to individually pick which variables should be in ascending and descending order:

```
arrange(ToothGrowth, len, dose)
arrange(ToothGrowth, desc(len), dose)
arrange(ToothGrowth, len, desc(dose))
arrange(ToothGrowth, desc(len), desc(dose))
```

It also has an elegant implementation:

```
arrange <- function (df, ...) {
  ord <- eval(substitute(order(...)), df, parent.frame())
  unrowname(df[ord, ])
}
```

And `desc` is just an ordinary function:

```
desc <- function (x) -xtfrm(x)
```

Reading the help for `xtfrm` is highly recommended if you're writing this sort of function.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems poised to become my replacement.  But I'm still curious how one would go about making a generic and its methods consistent, since it comes up fairly often for me.  Also, syntactically, a sort() method would seem to keep things consistent with other data types.  But that's some pretty code :-)

Comment: `?arrange` indicates that: "# NOTE: plyr functions do NOT preserve row.names". This makes this excellent function suboptimal if one wants to keep `row.names`. Why not add a `keep.row.names=FALSE` option?

Comment: @landroni because I don't think that they're a good idea - it's better to add them as an explicit variable.

Comment: I see. But still, this is standard functionality associated with `data.frame`, at least as far as most users are concerned, and it would be useful to give those users the choice.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Gavin that `x` must come first. I'd put the `decreasing` parameter after the `formula` though - since it probably isn't used that much, and hardly ever as a positional argument.

The `formula` argument would be used much more and therefore should be the second argument. I also strongly agree with @Gavin that it should be called `formula`, and not `form`.

```
sort.data.frame(x, formula = ~ ., decreasing = FALSE, ...) {
  ...
}
```

You might want to extend the `decreasing` argument to allow a logical vector where each TRUE/FALSE value corresponds to one column in the formula:

```
d <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=10:1)
sort(d, ~ A+B, decreasing=c(A=TRUE, B=FALSE)) # sort by decreasing A, increasing B
```

Comment: I'd *like* the formula argument to be second, but I'm not sure I can have it that way and still have it be an S3 class.  I'd like to not have a `decreasing` at all, since the formula takes negative arguments which implies decreasing.

Comment: @gsk3, `sort.int` has `decreasing=...` only as the fourth parameter, so my guess is you can have `formula=...` as your second.  I suspect you can also use `decreasing=NULL` and ignore this parameter in your code (in the same way that `sort.int` ignores `decreasing` when `partial=TRUE`).  PS.  All of this can be found in `?sort`.

Comment: @Andrie, even if you flip the order, because `decreasing` is named second in the generic function, it grabs the positional argument.  So it doesn't help, sadly.

Comment: @Andrie `sort.int` is not method of `sort`. There is no class `int`. You could see implemented methods with `methods(sort)`.